# sharedpreferences in service does not save when app is not open

Tags: android, listview, android-service, android-sharedpreferences

When I send notification and app does not open already,I cant see my notification on listview in mainactivity.When I send notification and app already is open,I see on listview.How can I see notifications on listview everytime I send notification?

### my service

```
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    SharedPreferences a=getSharedPreferences("noti",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=a.edit();
    editor.putInt("i",a.getInt("i",0)+1);
    editor.putString(String.valueOf(a.getInt("i",0)+1),messageBody);
    editor.apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.farmer)
            .setContentTitle("Zengin Çiftçi")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

### my mainactivity

```
   a=getSharedPreferences("noti",MODE_PRIVATE);
    for(int i=a.getInt("i",0);i>0;i--){
        liste.add(a.getString(String.valueOf(i),""));
    }
```

Comment: use `editor.commit()` instead of `editor.apply()` and see if working

Comment: Unfortunately,it did not work